# How do I hide the latitude and longitude lines in Google Earth Pro (Mac)

Tags: google-earth

I want to hide the lines.

My Google Earth version: `7.3.6.9326 (64-bit)`

Build date: `Tuesday, December 13, 2022 5:08:45 AM UTC`

I have checked off every item, but the lines are still there:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does [How Get Rid of the Grid on Google Earth](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/rid-grid-google-earth-43684.html) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, Ctrl+L works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I hide the latitude and longitude lines?

There is a menu option to remove them as well as a keyboard shortcut:

> **Using the Main Menu**
>
> 1. Navigate to your desired location in Google Earth. The latitude and longitude lines load at a scale dependent on your zoom level. Loading
>    may take a few moments, depending on the speed of your computer.
> 2. Click “View” on the main Google Earth menu.
> 3. Click “Lat/Lon Grid” on the drop-down menu to remove the grid.
>
> **Using Your Keyboard**
>
> 1. Navigate to your desired map location. The grid loads and adjusts its size accordingly.
> 2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Google Earth removes the grid from your map.

Source: [How Get Rid of the Grid on Google Earth](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/rid-grid-google-earth-43684.html)